# Shack Hartmann lenslet array design

Tags: optics, sensor

What is the relationship between the number of pixels on a CCD that are dedicated to a lenslet array and the number of pixels covered by the focal spot from one lenslet array on the CCD? 
Specifically how does the trade off looks like between how many pixels that could be dedicated per lenslet and per focal spot and the error introduced in centroid calculation using a simple center of mass approach? The sensing wavelength in use for the application of interest is in the infrared region.

Is there a way to calculate the effect of increasing the pixels covered by the focal spot and dedicated to each lenslet in the array and the noise and error introduced to the centroid calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess you're not talking about a [plenoptic](https://www.lytro.com/)
 camera but rather  a [Wavefront Sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shack%E2%80%93Hartmann_wavefront_sensor).

Given that I worked for a company called Adaptive Optics Associates for many years, I'm painfully familiar with Hartmann sensors.    In brief (and you should read the references), your tradeoff is between maximum tilt dynamic range, or wavefront tilt, per subaperture, and response linearity & precision.

You get to choose the focal length of your lenslet, which defines the Airy disc diameter.  The Airy radius corresponds to one wave of tilt.

Next, compare that with the size of each pixel.  In the simplest case of a 2x2 "quad cell", your spot will be completely on one side of the null point  at 1 wave of tilt, so beyond that you know only the direction, not magnitude of tilt.

When you "assign" a larger number of pixels per lenslet, say 5x5 pixels, then you can observe the focussed spot's motion across all the pixel boundaries.  The raw output will have "wiggles" but these can be calibrated out of the system.

I would like to post a link to the famous MIT-LL "Adaptive Optics Coloring Book" but it seems to have disappeared from the 'net.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the wavefront sensor. <a href="http://example.com" title="example">example</a>

Comment: In this paper http://opticalengineering.spiedigitallibrary.org/mobile/article.aspx?articleid=1088887, the minimum focal spot width on the detector was set to cover 8 pixels. I am trying to understand why use such a large number of pixels if each pixel contributes to the read out noise of the detector which in turn contributes more to the error of determining the centroid location.I already know my pixel size I am just trying to choose focal length and diameter of the lenslets given the dynamic range, and sensitvity specifications.How can I set the pixel per lenslet & per spot?

Comment: Yes, you can add the SNR to your tradespace -- if you add pixels you'll need more light input to get the same SNR, so it depends on what you can tolerate, what your bandwidth requirements are, etc.